# Windows Phone 7 - Move Content above Keyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have page containing 4 textboxes and a button. The content is within ScrollViewer. When user goes to the last textbox, the button below it is 50% visible. So, to click it, user has to click on non-focusable area to hide the keyboard and then click on button.

Is there any way to move the ScrollViewer up? Or move the content up so that the button below focused textbox can be seen 100%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to remove the buttons on the page and replace them with buttons in the ApplicationBar as this is always viewable below the SIP.

If this is not a solution you can implement (from a design view-point there is no reason to not do this but sometimes these decisions come from elsewhere) then you could look to use the [ScrollToVerticalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method to try and bring the desired item into view.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please give me some example of how to implement second solution? ScrollToVerticalOffset does not seem to work. It does not move the content up.

Comment: @Chitan I'd always look to use the first solution. To get the scrolling to work you may need to also adjust the height of the container when the SIP is displayed but you'll need ht e mango tools to detect this consistently.

Comment: First solution looks good but it breaks the consistency with other platforms. For second option, I already have mango tools. Can you please tell me what you are referring to as container's height?

Comment: @Christian if you're trying to keep things looking identical on multiple platforms you'll create substandard apps for each. Remember, your users see your app in the context of other apps on the phone they are using, not in the contecxt of your app on multiple platforms. Regarding the container, I mean the control (probably a Grid) which you have which contains the scrollviewer (if you haven't got one you'll need one) which contains all the texboxes, etc.

Comment: Excellent explanation for consistency. thank you. I will also look at solution and let you know.

Comment: @ChintanShah - Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you read [Alex Sorokoletov's article](http://sorokoletov.com/2011/08/windows-phone-70-handling-text-entry-screens/) on how to transform the view. It might be of help for your problem.